# case expression for various SQL updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, case

I'm struggling with a case expression to determine which update statement to make. Is the below even possible or should i make separate update stored procedures for each update?

```
 IF (SELECT pick FROM warehouse WHERE order_no = @order_no and pick = @pick) is null
    CASE @pick 
    when 1 then
            UPDATE warehouse
            SET pick = @pick, startpickdate=@dchar, startpicktime=@tchar
            where order_no=@order_no
    when 2 then
            UPDATE warehouse
            SET pick = @pick, endpickdate=@dchar, endpicktime=@tchar
            where order_no=@order_no
    when 0 then
            UPDATE warehouse
            SET pick = @pick, endpickdate='', endpicktime='',startpickdate='', startpicktime=''
            where order_no=@order_no
END
GO
```

Comment: You might want to think about using IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT pick FROM warehouse WHERE order_no = @order_no and pick = @pick).

Comment: Which DBMS?  I'm assuming SQL Server based upon your other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to conditionally update your columns, this approach would work for you

```
UPDATE Warehouse
SET Pick = @pick
   , startPickDate = CASE @pick
                        WHEN 1 THEN @dchar
                        WHEN 2 THEN startPickDate
                        WHEN 0 THEN ''
                     END
   , startPickTime = CASE @pick
                        WHEN 1 THEN @tchar
                        WHEN 2 THEN startPickTime
                        WHEN 0 THEN ''
                     END
   , ...
WHERE order_no = @order_no
```

Comment: -1 Not semantically the same when @pick not in (0,1,2). Also potential to fire triggers that test UPDATE(`<column>`) unnecessarily

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi You are correct, but you can easily add an ELSE case if you have the potential for values outside of the 0-2 range.  Most triggers I have dealt with also check that the Inserted value differs from the Deleted value- you are correct though, certain triggers would pose problems.

Comment: I'm nervous about changing query semantics when dealing with newbies. Because they won't actually understand that things have changed.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi Good point. (Also, thanks for the reason for the -1)

Answer (score 1):

[`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is not used for T-SQL [control-of-flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx).  As such, one method is to continue your use of `IF` (actual control-of-flow), which would allow you to keep your update statements simpler, though there would be one for each branch:

```
IF (SELECT pick FROM warehouse WHERE order_no = @order_no AND pick = @pick) IS NULL BEGIN
    IF @pick = 1 BEGIN
        UPDATE warehouse
        SET pick = @pick, startpickdate=@dchar, startpicktime=@tchar
        WHERE order_no=@order_no
    END
    ELSE IF @pick = 2 BEGIN
        UPDATE warehouse
        SET pick = @pick, endpickdate=@dchar, endpicktime=@tchar
        WHERE order_no=@order_no
    END
    ELSE IF @pick = 0 BEGIN
        UPDATE warehouse
        SET pick = @pick, endpickdate='', endpicktime='',startpickdate='', startpicktime=''
        WHERE order_no=@order_no
    END
END
GO
```

If you're in a stored proc anyway, you might find this more maintainable, though that is certainly subjective.

I would probably lean toward this method rather than one big combined update statement using `case` since you are updating different columns in each case.